# Sequence of real numbers in lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology

Are there any bounded strictly increasing sequences of real numbers that converge in the lower limit topology?

I think I found an example:

$x_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$  , $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_n)=e$ , $x_n \in (1,e), n > 0$

Then $B_l(e)=$ {[e, $\epsilon$), $\epsilon$>$0$} - basis of neighbors for e,

$x_n \to e \iff ∀\epsilon>0, n_\epsilon \in \Bbb N$  so  $∀n \in \Bbb N, n  \geq n_\epsilon, x_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \in [e, \epsilon)$

But this is false, because $x_n \in (1,e)$

What am I doing it wrong? Aren't there any sequences?

Comment: If $x_n \uparrow x$ in the order, then $[x,x+1)$ contains no points of the sequence.

Comment: I think you are calculating the limit of $x_n$ with respect to euclidean topology in the first expression, which leads to confusion. You can prove that there are no such sequence using Henno's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a strictly increasing sequence $(x_n)$ and an arbitrary real number $y$.
If $y$ is not an upper bound of $\{x_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ then *eventually* $y < x_n$, for some $N$ and $n\geq N$. This means that $(x_n)$ is not eventually in $[y,x_N)$ which is required from a sequence convergent to $y$.
If $y$ is an upper bound, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is no point of $(x_n)$ in $[y,\epsilon)$ which is a weaker condition than the last one. In both cases $(x_n)$ can not converge to $y$, so no strictly increasing sequence is convergence and the answer to your question is no.

While an indirect proof is easier, I think this direct approach is better in an educational sense.